# Asynchronous dumping of requests received on FASTAPI using background tasks into a Kinesis Stream is increasing the response time drastically

Tags: async-await, fastapi, amazon-eks, background-task, amazon-kinesis-firehose

On receiving a request in a fast api endpoint, I am adding an async task to BackgroundTasks, which in turns uses a boto client to connect to kinesis and dumps the data onto the stream.

The endpoint method is as follows:

```
@app.post("/endpoint")
async def base_api(req: RequestAPIModel, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    try:
        jsonObj = req.model_dump()
        resp = prepareResponse(jsonObj)
        return resp
    finally:
        background_tasks.add_task(stream_data, jsonObj, resp)
```

The stream_data method is as follows:

```
kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis', region_name='us-east-1')

async def stream_data(req, apiResp):
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    dt_stamp = timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
    dt = timestamp.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    data = {'request': req, 'response': apiResp, 'timestamp': dt_stamp}
    
    record = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    
    try:
        response = kinesis_client.put_record(StreamName=delivery_stream_name, Data=record, PartitionKey=dt)
        if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            print(f"Record streamed successfully with stream SequenceNumber {response['SequenceNumber']}")
        else:
            print("Error sending Record")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

The cpu utilisation is not spiking with the initial config of 4 pods on EKS, but to increase the number of executers, I have increased the number of pods to 8 on EKS worker group where this API Application is hosted, but that did not help as well.

Comment: `kinesis_client.put_record` doesn't seem to be an async call?

Comment: @MatsLindh, no it's not. But what I am having trouble understanding is that, why would a background task have any effect on the response time of the api.

Comment: Because the background task, which is not async, keeps the event loop busy and never gives up time for any other tasks to run. As long as that piece of code is waiting for a response from your kinesis endpoint _nothing else runs_, since it never gives up processing power to other coroutines.

Comment: @MatsLindh Can I trigger kinesis put_record call using lambda and make the lambda call async in the API?

Comment: If the inner call isn't async compatible, you'll still end up with the same problem. If you don't have an async compatible client for kinesis, it might be better to use a queue system in between - i.e. make an async compatible call to a queue, and let a queue worker handle the call that takes time.